# Permission denied error when setting up local Spark instance and running pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am setting up a local Spark instance on Windows to use with PySpark as described in this guide (but with spark-3.0.0 / hadoop 2.7 instead): https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10.
I can startup Spark with:

```
C:\Spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-shell.cmd
```

and connect to it with `http://localhost:4040/` in my browser (I see the Spark GUI).

But when am running the Python pyspark example with

```
C:\Spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\examples>run-example SparkPi
```

it throws an Permission Denied error like in this trace:

```
21/03/08 10:51:03 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.0.0
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO ResourceUtils: Resources for spark.driver:

21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Spark Pi
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: #####
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: #####
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
21/03/08 10:51:04 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(#####); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(#####); groups with modify permissions: Set()
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 63213.
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-dce03954-27a7-484d-8e54-f552b21433f7
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MiB
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT:4040
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///C:/Spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/scopt_2.12-3.7.1.jar at spark://WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT:63213/jars/scopt_2.12-3.7.1.jar with timestamp 1615197065578
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///C:/Spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar at spark://WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT:63213/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar with timestamp 1615197065579
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 63260.
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT:63260
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, NLLR4000250910.solon.prd, 63260, None)
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager NLLR4000250910.solon.prd:63260 with 366.3 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT, 63260, None)
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, NLLR4000250910.solon.prd, 63260, None)
21/03/08 10:51:05 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, NLLR4000250910.solon.prd, 63260, None)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: reduce at SparkPi.scala:38
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (reduce at SparkPi.scala:38) with 2 output partitions
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (reduce at SparkPi.scala:38)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkPi.scala:34), which has no missing parents
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.1 KiB, free 366.3 MiB)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1816.0 B, free 366.3 MiB)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT:63260 (size: 1816.0 B, free: 366.3 MiB)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1200
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkPi.scala:34) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1))
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7393 bytes)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7393 bytes)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
21/03/08 10:51:06 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT:63213/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar with timestamp 1615197065579
21/03/08 10:51:06 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT/192.168.#.#:63213
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:253)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:195)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:392)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$openChannel$4(NettyRpcEnv.scala:360)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:719)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:535)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$updateDependencies$7(Executor.scala:869)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$updateDependencies$7$adapted(Executor.scala:860)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:237)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:860)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:404)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Permission denied: no further information: WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT/192.168.#.#:63213
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[snip]
```

When running it on a different machine with seemingly the same config where it works fine, I get this trace on the part where the Exception is thrown on the other trace:

```
[snip]

21/03/08 08:00:22 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
21/03/08 08:00:22 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
21/03/08 08:00:22 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT:63646/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar with timestamp 1615186820489
21/03/08 08:00:22 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT/10.121.#.#:63646 after 86 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
21/03/08 08:00:22 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.EXT:63646/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar to C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-54a13d9f-9064-4f34-ba81-af49b18d9a0c\userFiles-24c3eabc-02a4-4aca-8abb-424431c6442f\fetchFileTemp5258763437798623210.tmp
21/03/08 08:00:24 INFO Executor: Adding file:/C:/Users/#####/AppData/Local/Temp/spark-54a13d9f-9064-4f34-ba81-af49b18d9a0c/userFiles-24c3eabc-02a4-4aca-8abb-424431c6442f/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar to class loader

[snip]
```

At first it seemed to me as a Firewall issue, but adding the executing java.exe as exeption to the firewall didn't solve the issue.

Does anyone know what I should try next to get this issue resolved?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @NishuTayal look at my answer to this post. Thanks for reminding me to add the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I could solve it by setting my SPARK_LOCAL_IP to localhost in my environment variables: Go to your Windows environment variables and set `SPARK_LOCAL_IP=localhost`

[image]